# Retrieve address from ABRecordRef

Tags: ios8, abrecordref

I need to get address information for calculating shipping and taxes rates for purchasing items on my app. I wanna use Apple Pay, thus I receive record as ABRecordRef instance. 
I've tried

```
NSString *zip = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(address, kABPersonAddressZIPKey));
```

but it causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm sure there should be a way to make it work, does anyone know it?

Comment: How is `address` defined and retrieved?

Comment: The problem seem to be in your "address" variable. Can you please share the code where you declared and initialised the "address" variable?

Comment: @LeoNatan I get it in `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` method — `paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *)controller didSelectShippingAddress:(ABRecordRef)address completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus, NSArray *, NSArray *))completion` callback.

Comment: @Tayyab I do not instanciate the instance — I receive it in `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewControllerDelegate` callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally:

```
CFTypeRef addressProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)address, kABPersonAddressProperty);
NSDictionary *addressDict = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex((CFArrayRef)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(addressProperty), 0);
```

Resulting dictionary looks like this:

```
{
    City = Hillsborough;
    CountryCode = us;
    State = CA;
    ZIP = 94010;
}
```

Comment: How are you getting the street information from this?

Comment: The full street address can be found in payment.ShippingAddress in the didAuthorizePayment callback.

Comment: At this point I wasn't interested in street — state, city and ZIP were enough to satisfy my needs.
The full address is available in didAuthorizePayment callback, as @JonC said.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have record identifier of a contact and you want to retrieve address. Your code will be like following,

```
ABRecordRef address[1];
address[0] = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(_addressBook, recId);
NSString *zip = (__bridge NSString *)(ABRecordCopyValue(address[0], kABPersonAddressZIPKey));
```

If you are doing something like this then please note in above code that you need to use **address[0]** instead of **address** in parameter to function **ABRecordCopyValue**.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not using address book in this case — I've got just a separate `ABRecordRef` instance. Do I need to create it?

Comment: hmmm. Then try calling CFRetain() function on instance that your receive. When you get the instance in callback then try calling CFRetain(name_of_instance) and once you are done with it then you can call CFRelease. I hope it helps.